# Validate start date and end date on AngularJS Bootstrap date picker?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I am new to Angular JS and I am trying to implement validation for date time picker in my Angular project.

I am using bootstrap date picker.

My HTML is :

```
<div>
    <form id="edit-profile" novalidate name="editReservationForm" autocomplete="off" class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="reservation.reservedFrom">Reserved From<sup>*</sup></label>
    <div class="controls input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
        <input type="text" class="span4" style="width:150px" name="reservedFrom" placeholder="Reserved From" data-ng-model="reservation.reservedFrom"
               validator="required" required-error-message="Date is required" valid-method="watch" id="startDate"/>
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- /controls -->
</div> <!-- /control-group -->
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="reservation.reservedTill">Reserved Till<sup>*</sup></label>
    <div class="controls input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
        <input type="text" style="width:150px" class="span4" name="reservedTill" placeholder="Reserved Till" data-ng-model="reservation.reservedTill"
               validator="required" required-error-message="Date is required" valid-method="watch" id="endDate" ng-change='checkErr(startDate,endDate)'/>
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
        </div>
        <span>{{errMessage}}</span>

    </div> <!-- /controls -->
</div> <!-- /control-group -->
 </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
```

My Controller is :

```
myApp.controller('editReservationController', ['$scope', '$filter', 'reservationResolved', 'pocResolved', 'accountResolved', 'reservationServices', '$location', '$state',
    function ($scope, $filter, reservationResolved, pocResolved, accountResolved, reservationServices, $location, $state) {
        $scope.reservation = new Object();
        $scope.accounts = accountResolved.data;
        $scope.pocs = pocResolved.data;
        $scope.reservation.employee = reservationResolved.data;
        $scope.updateReservation = function () {
            if ($scope.editReservationForm.$valid) {
                reservationServices.updateReservation($scope.reservation).then(function (result) {
                    $scope.data = result.data;
                    if (!result.data.error) {
                        $state.transitionTo('employeeTalentPool', {
                            id: $state.params.id
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        $scope.checkErr = function (startDate, endDate) {
            $scope.errMessage = '';
            var curDate = new Date();

            if (new Date(startDate) > new Date(endDate)) {
                $scope.errMessage = 'End Date should be greater than start date';
                return false;
            }
            if (new Date(startDate) < curDate) {
                $scope.errMessage = 'Start date should not be before today.';
                return false;
            }
        };

        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $location.path("/reservations");
        }
    }]);
```

I am totally new to Angular and I'm trying to understand it by doing projects. Can anyone have a check and provide a solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to pass in the `startDate` and `endDate` variables into the `ng-change` method on your second datepicker; you are already tracking those variables on your `$scope` with `ng-model`.

```
$scope.checkErr = function() {
  var start = new Date($scope.reservation.reservedFrom),
      end = new Date($scope.reservation.reservedTill);

  if (end < start) {
    $scope.errorMsg = "End must be after start";
  }

  ... other logic ...
};
```

---

Additionally, it may be best to just prevent a user from making bad choices.

The two errors you seem to want to guard against are: 1) the user chooses a `startDate` before today and 2) the user chooses an `endDate` before the `startDate`.

Both of the errors above can be prevented by modifying the `minDate` option within `datepicker-options`. Check out the `$watch` in [**this plunker**](https://embed.plnkr.co/5f3ZfXZBmIoukHny9hqK/) -- each time we select a new start date, we can modify the `minDate` option for the end date and prevent user input issues.

---

**Update (per request)**

The plunker shows two datepickers, both of which have their own custom `datepicker-options` bound as $scope variables -- we'll be able to modify these `datepicker-options` to change the behavior of each `datepicker`.

Defaulting `startDateOptions` "minDate" to today (within the CTRL) makes it impossible for a user to pick a `startDate` before today (solving the first issue you were trying to prevent).

Placing a [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) on the `startDate` allows us to update the `endDateOptions` after any a change of the `startDate`. This allows us to restrict a users choices for the `endDate` input by setting `minDate` to whatever the `startDate` is (solving the second issue of choosing an `endDate` before a `startDate`).

There is also some logic in the $watch to adjust `endDate` where it makes sense (like if we first selected a valid `endDate`, but then selected a new `startDate` that would make that `endDate` invalid).

Comment: So how should I use the code in the plunker to match my case? Like ng-model=?   Can you please make the change in your answer by including the functionality shown in plunker? That would be a great help for me to understand how it works.

Comment: Update :) The plunker is just for illustration -- I would keep your `ng-model` implementation however you want it. Don't feel like you have to adopt the `datepicker-options` above, your original approach with error messages was valid too.